# Verify SHA512-CRYPT hash of dovecot with PHP

Tags: php

I am building a simple management interface for my mail server setup and therefore I try to connect the authentication to my mail accounts in the database as they are used by Dovecot.

I use the `SHA512-CRYPT` algorithm in Dovecot and referring to this blog post https://mad9scientist.com/dovecot-password-creation-php/ I can create password from my PHP application that can be verified via the `doveadm pw -t` command.

```
$password = "123456";
$salt = substr(sha1(rand()), 0, 16);
$hashedPassword = "{SHA512-CRYPT}" . crypt($password, "$6$$salt");
// Example: $hashedPassword: {SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0e7d3217f1df9e8d$sIrNt9Q1t/lVOy/QKfMFpp.0Qyod0v59Jb7BG6mQ4tMtji7B/f9CaOD6JOuY9ftXt566F7/UG6JRG3wPRYUhP1
```

Then verifying this Hash with dovecot is successfull:

```
$ doveadm pw -t '{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0e7d3217f1df9e8d$sIrNt9Q1t/lVOy/QKfMFpp.0Qyod0v59Jb7BG6mQ4tMtji7B/f9CaOD6JOuY9ftXt566F7/UG6JRG3wPRYUhP1' -p "123456"

{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0e7d3217f1df9e8d$sIrNt9Q1t/lVOy/QKfMFpp.0Qyod0v59Jb7BG6mQ4tMtji7B/f9CaOD6JOuY9ftXt566F7/UG6JRG3wPRYUhP1 (verified)
```

Now I want to verify this stored hash agains the password the user provides when signing in to my application.

Using PHP's `password_verify`function however returns false:

```
password_verify('123456',  '{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$0e7d3217f1df9e8d$sIrNt9Q1t/lVOy/QKfMFpp.0Qyod0v59Jb7BG6mQ4tMtji7B/f9CaOD6JOuY9ftXt566F7/UG6JRG3wPRYUhP1')
```

How can I verify the hash correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefix `'{SHA512-CRYPT}'` is not recognised by `password_verify`/`crypt`. If you simply omit it, the hash verifies. I.e., put only exactly what `crypt` returns back into `password_verify`.

```
password_verify('123456', '$6$0e7d3217f1df9e8d$sIrNt9Q1t/lVOy/QKfMFpp.0Qyod0v59Jb7BG6mQ4tMtji7B/f9CaOD6JOuY9ftXt566F7/UG6JRG3wPRYUhP1')
```